# UITableView Cell control customize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I need to customize an `UITableview` control like the picture, [image]

Here i need to place the RE-ORDERING control to left side, is it possible here?

Answer (score 0):

@ Harish Saran -- You can customize table view cell. Just create on class(customCell.h) extending tableviewcell. In that class create buttons/ImageView whatever you want. and place in cell's contentview.

Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method create cell object of customCell.h, and just assign image for button/ImageView allocated in customCell.h

Comment: that is an custom control, re-ordering control is default control which will come at right side of tableview cell... i need that control in left side..like in the picture..